# Messages folder for the class is not from 'pages' and 'components' packages

Tags: java, properties, tapestry

In Tapestry, `.properties` files with localized messages are located in `page`, `component` and application message catalogs. I have class is not from `pages` and `components` packages, in which I want to inject messages in the usual way:

```
@Inject
private Messages messages;
```

to later get localized messages with

```
String msg = messages.get("message-key");
```

I tried to locate `.properties` file to the corresponging folder (i.e., for class `src/main/java/nonPageOrComponentPackage/Foo.java` to `scr/main/resources/nonPageOrComponentPackage/Foo.properties`), as it is done for `page` and `component` classes, but it didn't work.

Do I need to somewhere specify the path to this `.properties` file? I tried to do it with method

```
public void contributeValidationMessagesSource(@NotNull Configuration<String> configuration) {
  configuration.add("/scr/main/resources/nonPageOrComponentPackage/Foo.properties");
}
```

in `AppModule`, but it didn't work too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanism of message retrieval is designed to be used inside pages/components only. You have application message catalog, it can be overriden by some number of base page/component catalogs and then be overriden by end page/component catalog. All this work only for pages and components.

If your class is not a page or a component you can inject only application message catalog using `@Inject` annotation. You can also contribute to `ComponentMessageSource` service to add some additional message bundles to application catalog.

```
@Contribute(ComponentMessagesSource.class)
public void contributeComponentMessagesSource(@Value("context:WEB-INF/mail") Resource mailMessages, OrderedConfiguration<Resource> configuration) {
  configuration.add("mail", mailMessages);
}
```

But you should understand that this message bundles will be available for all pages/components and services.

The other way to get access to some specific message bundle is to use MessageImpl. But this way is tricky. It uses tapestry internal class.

```
messages = MessagesImpl.forClass(Foo.class);
```